# Enforcing a condition in a For Loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to enforce an IF condition in a For loop but it seems not working here. I have a snippet code here:

```
for iterate in range(N):
    for rows in range(rows):
        vector1 = function1(x, rows)
        x = vector1
        vector2 = function2(z, rows)
        z = vector2
        if a <= angle_between(x, z) <= b:    
            break
```

Here, "function1", "function2" and "angle_between" are all already defined functions. The "function1" and "function2" are called simultaneously in every loop and I want a situation where the ForLoop would stop at the If statement. However, when I ran my code and checked the final output of "angle_between", it was not in the range of (a, b). Was I wrong in my implementation here? Would appreciate any guide, please.

Comment: Can you show what data `rows` and `N` contain?

Comment: These are mere random data

Answer (score 0):

Your only breaking out of the inner loop. Try this:

```
done = False
for iterate in range(N):
    for rows in range(rows):
        vector1 = function1(x, rows)
        x = vector1
        vector2 = function2(z, rows)
        z = vector2
        if a <= angle_between(x, z) <= b:    
            done = True
            break
    if done:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

To break out of both loops from within the inner loop without using a variable you can put an else clause outside the inner loop and continue until the if statement is true.

```
for iterate in range(N):
    for rows in range(rows):
        vector1 = function1(x, rows)
        x = vector1
        vector2 = function2(z, rows)
        z = vector2
        if a <= angle_between(x, z) <= b:    
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, Jab, for pointing this out. However, I still don't get values of "angle_between" between (a,b). What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the values of any of your variables, what you're trying to achieve with the loops or what your functions contain, it's hard to tell what's wrong. It could be many things.

It might be that you didn't break out of your second for loop. It might be there's a flaw in the logic of your function.

It might also be that you're mutating the value of `rows` and then reusing it in the next iteration of your for loop.

Example:

```
rows = 5
N = 5
for iterate in range(N):
    print(rows)
    for rows in range(rows):
```

The first iteration of `for rows in range(rows):` will be 5.
After that looping 5 times the value of `rows` will be 4 and it will use that the next time it starts your inner for loop.

Comment: Thanks Axe319. My goal basically is to apply the functions to all the rows, one after the other, until the last row. However, this may not yield the desired result(the IF condition) and would require to start the procedure all over again. I hope this explains better

The functions are just simple functions that do straightforward computations like:

def function1(x, i):
    vector = x + (y[i] - A[i, :] @ x)*(A[i] / (norm(A[i])**2))
    return vector

A, y are already defined matrices and vectors